# how to copy the key from master node to slave node?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, openstack-nova

I am creating a cluster using 4 instances in OpenStack.
i am trying to copy the key from master to slave but getting below error.
I am not sure whether`hduser@madhu-master-17129141:/home/ubuntu$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub madhu-slave1-17129141
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Permission denied (publickey).`
 i missed anything

Comment: try ssh-copy-id with sudo

Comment: Probably better question for [unix.se]